# Rmagick crop to same image?

Tags: ruby, image, rmagick

I have find that when you want to crop an image in Rmagick, it doesn't mutate the current image object, but it returns a new one.

So, if I have:

```
@image = Magick::ImageList.new(path)
@cropped = @image.crop(10,10,20,20)
```

I wonder if the following code would be a good solution in terms of if I want to have always @image to contain the current image that is being manipulated.

```
@image = Magick::ImageList.new(path)
@image = @image.crop(10,10,20,20)
```

This works, but would I be having two images here? Should I destroy the first one before reassigning to @image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an in-place version of [`crop`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#crop) called [`crop!`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#crop_bang):

> `img.crop!(x, y, width, height) -> self`
>   `img.crop!(gravity, x, y, width, height) -> self`
>   `img.crop!(gravity, width, height) -> self`
>
> The in-place form of `crop`.

so you can say:

```
@image = Magick::ImageList.new(path).crop!(10,10,20,20)
```

if you want to avoid making a copy. Or you could let the GC deal with it and say:

```
@image = Magick::ImageList.new(path).crop(10,10,20,20) # No `!` here
```